# Store output from the Main to a Class

Tags: java, arrays, class, output

This is part of the code I have in my `Main` method. I want to store the output of one particular array in a new class( u can see it in the comment in the code.

```
    int splitNum = 0;
    BufferedWriter out = 
       new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("data.txt"), "ISO-8859-1"));

    ArrayList<Split> allSplits = new ArrayList<Split>();

    int[]version=new int[(int) NUM_OF_SPLITS];
    while((numRead = (reader.read(buf))) != -1){
       String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);

                   version[splitNum]=1;

     //     I need to store the output of the array version in a new class             


       String encrypted = Encryptor.run(readData);
       Split split = new Split(encrypted, splitNum);
       System.out.println( "Split:" + split.blocks + "\n\n" );
       WatchDog.run(split);
       Permutator.run(split);
       System.out.println( "Final Split:" + split.blocks + "\n\n");
      allSplits.add(split);


       buf = new char[StaticData.splitSize];
       splitNum++;
    }
```

It seems something basic, but I just can't think of it right now. Any help? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a "new class"?

Comment: I mean that the output now is in the MainClass, I want to copy it in another independant class outside of the Main called for example Version

Answer (score 0):

decalre a class named ArrayStore

declare a ArrayList in that class.

```
public class ArrayStore
{
private ArrayList list1;

public ArrayStore()
{
this.list1 = new ArrayList();
}

void addInList(String text)
{
    this.list1.add(text);
}

ArrayList getList()
{
    return this.list1;
}
}
```

instantiate that class and its arraylist after before the looping.

```
ArrayStore store= new ArrayStore();
```

add elements generated from the reader to this list.

```
while((numRead = (reader.read(buf))) != -1){
       String readData = String.valueOf(buf, 0, numRead);

                   version[splitNum]=1;
```

//Class addition code starts here

```
     store.addInList(readData);
```

thats it.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to store readData but the version[] so do I need to keep the array list or should I change the type?